# Virtual Machine for running Red Hat on Windows Vista

Tags: virtual-machine

It looks like there are a variety of virtual machine offerings available.  What is the best one to use with Vista as the host operating system and Red Hat Linux as the guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: Virtualbox and VMWare Server both look like great suggestions.  Would suggestions change at all if I pointed out this is for business use and there is no hesitation paying a reasonable amount for the software, or is one of those two the way to go?

Comment: Yup. If it is for business use, I would suggest you to go with bare metal VMWare EXSi software. Running VMWare or Virtual box on 32 bit/ 4 GB RAM will be no good.

Running Virtual machines on Windows are for learning and evaluating. Business do demand more better!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [VMWare Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/)... it's free and it's great.  Also, this question would be better asked at [ServerFault.com](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know ServerFault existed.